# Flutter: draw Path with CatmullRomSpline

Tags: flutter, canvas, spline

I have a list of Offset objects and I can create CatmullRomSpline. But how I can create a Path object from dart:ui for painting it in CustomPainter class?

Comment: you can not do that directly - the only way is drawing it point by point (line by line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this library for smoothing your path https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2

```
// zigzag is a list of coordinates
final Path path = new Path.from(zigzag);

// Result is below
final Path steps = path.equalize(8,smoothPath: true);
```